# Are there any image effects libraries (e.g. lomo) for Android or iPhone?

Tags: iphone, android, ios, image-processing

are there any image effects (e.g. lomo, watercolor, sketch ...etc) libries can be used on mobile device and suitable for mobile device?

There are libraries like **JJIL**, **simple-iphone-image-processing**, **JH labs**, **imageMagick porting to iphone** and **opencv** have been mentioned in various previous posts.

I want libraries that I don't need to care about the algorithm of effect, but lots of libraries mentioned above are this type of libraries.

What I need are libraries that already have done effects functions and I just call the functions to apply effects on photos (It is ok to set parameters and attributes by myself when I use it).

Are there any more suggestions? 
Free is good, commercial would be fine.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the effects API from Aviary. Here: http://developers.aviary.com/

I never used it though, so I can't say if that's exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This seems great, but its mobile sdk is not available now. It's a pitty. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially worth your while:

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)

[Simple iPhone Image Processing](http://code.google.com/p/simple-iphone-image-processing/)

Comment: I forgot to mention OpenCV in my original post. OpenCV is good but it still need to understand lots of details about the effect that I want to use. What I need is photo effects libraries that doesn't need to implements effect algorithm by myself. Very appreciate your kindly help.